# Make jQuery variable out of click event available to other functions

Tags: jquery, function, variables, this, global

I need to send a variable through a method inside the callback of another function. The variable should be whichever nav link was clicked. Instead of feebly explaining, here is the code. The logic is off, but you'll get the idea.

```
/* Make a variable out of which link was clicked */

$('nav a').click(function(){
    var $nav = $(this);
});

$('nav').localScroll({
    duration: 500,
    easing:'easeOutSine',
    axis:'xy',
    onAfter: function(){

/* send that variable through aktivator() in the callback of localScroll() */

        $nav.aktivator();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "that variable" means? Which variable do you want to send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `$nav` in a higher scope:

```
var $nav;

$('nav a').click(function(){
    $nav = $(this);
});

$('nav').localScroll({
    /* ... */
    onAfter: function(){
        $nav.aktivator();
    }
});
```

Now both areas can access it, or invoke its methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $nav; //higher

$('nav a').click(function(){
    $nav = $(this);
});

$('nav').localScroll({
    duration: 500,
    easing:'easeOutSine',
    axis:'xy',
    onAfter: function(){
        $nav.aktivator(); //available
    }
});
```